# Angular js pass Data from Config Controller to other Controll

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation i would like to pass data from control (within config) to the external controller. I have tried factory to pass data around, however after the data gets changed, it still remain 0 (not sure where i have done wrong) is there a way i can pass the data to the **navCtrl** after the DynamicController change? Thanks for help

```
    var app = angular.module('fccrm', ['ngRoute']);

    app.factory('idService', function(){
        var id = 0;
        var itemsService = {};

        itemsService.set = function(val) {
            id = val;
        };
        itemsService.get = function() {
            return id;
        };

        return itemsService;
    })

    app.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', 'idService', function($scope, idService){
        $scope.disable = 'disabled';
        console.log(idService.get());
    }])

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/:page/:id', {
            template: '',
            controller: DynamicController
        });
    }])

    function DynamicController($scope, $routeParams, $http, idService)
    {
        var templateUrl = '/index.php?controller=lead&action=' + $routeParams.page + '&id=' + $routeParams.id;
        idService.set($routeParams.id);
        $http.post(templateUrl).success(function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);            
        })
    }
```

Comment: Where is the navCtrl being triggered? Are you calling it from within the view? If navCtrl is called after DynamicController then the value in navCtrl will be 0.

Comment: @CalM the navCtrl trigger first it's in the view, i can't get it trigger after the DynamicController. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value to keep in sync - regardless of the load order, then you should use the $scope. That's what it was designed for.

Depending on what you want to do with the value, you have a number of options.

#### Display the value in the view

`$scope.displayId = idService.get()` or better still, why not just add the id the `$rootScope` and access it from there?

#### You want to be notified when the value changes in navCtrl, so you can do further processing

You can either use `$rootScope.$broadcast('routeParamIdChanged', id)` in DynamicCtrl and then listen for the change using `$scope.$on('routeParamIdChanged, fn(ev, id){})` or you could create a `$watch` which checks the service.

Comment: Great, please mark as correct - if it works for you. :-)